# fuzzy_left_join with match_fun %in%

Tags: r, fuzzyjoin

Some data

```
example_df <- data.frame(
  url = c('blog/blah', 'blog/?utm_medium=foo', 'blah', 'subscription/apples', 'UK/something'),
  numbs = 1:5
)

lookup_df <- data.frame(
  string = c('blog', 'subscription', 'UK'),
  group = c('blog', 'subs', 'UK')
)


library(fuzzyjoin)
data_combined <- example_df %>% 
  fuzzy_left_join(lookup_df, by = c("url" = "string"), 
                  match_fun = `%in%`)

data_combined
                   url numbs string group
1            blog/blah     1   <NA>  <NA>
2 blog/?utm_medium=foo     2   <NA>  <NA>
3                 blah     3   <NA>  <NA>
4  subscription/apples     4   <NA>  <NA>
5         UK/something     5   <NA>  <NA>
```

I expected data_combined to have values for string and group where there's a match based on match_fun. Instead all NA.

Example, the first value of string in lookup_df is 'blog'. Since this is `%in%` the first value of example_df string, expected a match with value 'blog' and 'blog' in string and group fields.

Comment: I think you may need `%like%` instead of `%in%`

Comment: Is this always looking for a match before `/`, then `example_df %>% mutate(string = str_remove(url, "\\/.*")) %>% left_join(lookup_df)`

Comment: RE your first comment, when trying like I get `Error in fuzzy_join(x, y, by, match_fun, mode = "left", ...) : 
  object '%like%' not found`

Comment: sorry, it is from data.table.  I think the second comment should work if the pattern you are matching is before the `/`

Comment: RE your second comment the only thing I know for sure with this data is that the string in lookup_df will always be a string same as or shorter than it's equivalent in example_df url?

Comment: Ah! Loading data.table got it to work but introduced another issue. It duplicates rows where the match is more than once in the lookup. Argh, today is a tough one.. There's no flag you know of along the lines 'just use the first match'?

Comment: it is duplicating.  I noticed that.  Can you try the code in the solution posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to do a partial match with the word before the `/` in the 'url' with the 'string' column in 'lookup_df', we could extract that substring as a new column and then do a `regex_left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringr)
example_df %>%
    mutate(string = str_remove(url, "\\/.*")) %>% 
    regex_left_join(lookup_df, by = 'string') %>%
    select(url, numbs, group)
```

-output

```
#                   url numbs group
#1            blog/blah     1  blog
#2 blog/?utm_medium=foo     2  blog
#3                 blah     3  <NA>
#4  subscription/apples     4  subs
#5         UK/something     5    UK
```

Comment: Perfect, this works and does not seem to duplicate! Why would it not duplicate? Welp, not complaining

Comment: @DougFir It would be the way the `%like%` is matching.  Also, it is better to do the match more directed instead of the whole url